# Does Sharekit still work?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, sharekit

When I try and use Facebook with Sharekit, it pops up the login dialog, I fill in my credentials and then it just disapears (it does this in the sample project as well)  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is Sharekit just defunked?  If so, any viable alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

Yes it does. And it gets better - there is a [new repo](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) on github, which aims to bring it alive again, from the flood of various forks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ShareKit on a current project. The Facebook integration performs this way sometimes, but I don't think it has anything to do with the library. Remember that the Facebook dialog is hosted by Facebook. It may have to do with a temporary hiccup on their end.

Comment: I'm using the following code, and everytime the facebook screen pops up, I enter my credentials it then disappears and does nothing further:     'SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zero-g-paddleball/id417260935?mt=8"];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm playing someGame on my iPhone! My Highscore is %i, think you can beat it?", 123]];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Share Me!"];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];'   Any idea why?  The sample project also does the same thing.

Comment: I have the same issue @Graeme. I am however able to post TEXT to facebook but then I cannot get rid of the popup ajaxy spinner dialog.

Answer (score 0):

`Sharekit` still works.  I love it and it saved me a ton of time.  It absolutely works.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue as well.

There is a bug with the sharekit when the user signing in has already authorized your app to access their facebook account.

If I go into facebook -> account settings -> apps and remove my app from the list of apps. I do not experience this bug the very next time I have to sign in to facebook through the sharekit.

I am working on a solution, as long as time permits!